# Cant find_elements with Selenium, Anaconda3, Python 3.6

Tags: python, selenium

I have installed Anaconda3, working with Python 3.6. Now installed Selenium 3.8 and the webdriver e.g. IE. The web browser starts and shows the google page, but the find_element_by_name does not work. I investigated the webpage and the search bar has the name="q". Can you help?

Here my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.get('https://google.de')
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
```

Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testbot.py", line 4, in <module>
    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 858, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == [name="q"]
```

Comment: Do time.sleep(4) & then try with xpath browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="q"]')

Comment: @ShekharSamanta Inducing `time.sleep(4)` is against all the best practices. Avoid them yourself and suggesting as well.

Comment: Ran your code with `webdriver.Chrome()` as I didn't have `IEDriver` and the code ran without any errors. Maybe the `IEDriver` is slow? If so, I'd recommend you to change to `chromedriver`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I installed Chrome and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error as such in your code block. But as you are using **`anaconda3`** a simple solution would be to induce **`WebDriverWait`** for the **`Search Box`** on **`https://google.de`** to be `clickable` as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.get('https://google.de')
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the element hasn't appeared on the page yet (it's not loaded). Try adding a browser.implicitly_wait(10) to make sure that you retry a few times before failing, or you could add an explicit wait for the element. You should look at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html